# Weird invalid block type error in Magento: 'Mage_Core_Exception'

Tags: magento-1.9

```
2015-06-29T16:00:02+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp: Mage_Imprint_Block_Content' in /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ung\xC3\xBCltiger Blo...')
#1 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('imprint/content', Array)
#2 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(164): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('imprint/content', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(134): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(502): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<style type="te...')
#6 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<style type="te...')
#7 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(442): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->getProcessedTemplate(Array, true)
#8 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(506): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#9 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('51', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#10 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1321): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#11 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Service/Sales/OrderConfirmation.php(47): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#12 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Observer/TransactionStatus/OrderConfirmation.php(57): Payone_Core_Model_Service_Sales_OrderConfirmation->sendMail(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#13 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Payone_Core_Model_Observer_TransactionStatus_OrderConfirmation->onAppointed(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Payone_Core_Model_Observer_TransactionStatus_OrderConfirmation), 'onAppointed', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('payone_core_tra...', Array)
#16 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Service/TransactionStatus/Process.php(127): Mage::dispatchEvent('payone_core_tra...', Array)
#17 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Service/TransactionStatus/Process.php(116): Payone_Core_Model_Service_TransactionStatus_Process->dispatchEvent('payone_core_tra...', Array)
#18 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Service/TransactionStatus/Execute.php(95): Payone_Core_Model_Service_TransactionStatus_Process->execute(Object(Payone_Core_Model_Domain_Protocol_TransactionStatus))
#19 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Service/TransactionStatus/Execute.php(63): Payone_Core_Model_Service_TransactionStatus_Execute->execute(Object(Payone_Core_Model_Domain_Protocol_TransactionStatus))
#20 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Cronjob/TransactionStatus/Worker.php(47): Payone_Core_Model_Service_TransactionStatus_Execute->executePending()
#21 [internal function]: Payone_Core_Model_Cronjob_TransactionStatus_Worker->execute(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#22 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(115): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#24 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#25 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#26 /usr/www/users/xxxxxxxx/shop/cron.php(46): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#27 {main}
```

Comment: have you any module name of imprint?

Comment: Hey Amit, thanks for your reply.

No, I do not have an imprint module running. But I managed to find out that whenever I look at the preview of a mail-template, the same error is written in the the exception.log.

This happens with the original mail-templates as well as with the copied templates I use for the shop.

Comment: Search in your code for 'imprint/content' and check the output. Looks like a wrong block definition.